# overload following optional argument

Tags: python, mypy, static-typing

I have a class `Animal` with a method `foo` which has different return types according to a boolean parameter `inplace` which follows an optional parameter `bar`. I'd like to overload the function so that the return type is known if the value of `inplace` is known

Here's my code:

```py
# main.py

from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Optional, overload, Literal 


class Animal:
    @overload
    def foo(self, bar=..., inplace: Literal[False]=...) -> Animal:
        ...

    @overload
    def foo(self, bar=..., inplace: Literal[True]=...) -> None:
        ...

    def foo(
        self, bar=None, inplace: bool = False
    ) -> Optional[Animal]:
        ...


reveal_type(Animal().foo(bar='a'))
reveal_type(Animal().foo(inplace=True))
reveal_type(Animal().foo(inplace=False))
```

```
$ mypy main.py
main.py:8: error: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types
main.py:21: note: Revealed type is 'main.Animal'
main.py:22: note: Revealed type is 'None'
main.py:23: note: Revealed type is 'main.Animal'
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=49da369f6343543769eed2060fa61639

How can I avoid the `Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types` error on line 8?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Optional, overload, Literal 


class Animal:

    # using defaults
    @overload
    def foo(self, bar=..., inplace: Literal[False]=...) -> Animal: ...

    # using inplace = True
    
    # with bar
    @overload
    def foo(self, bar, inplace: Literal[True]) -> None: ...

    # without bar
    @overload
    def foo(self, *, inplace: Literal[True]) -> None: ...

    # with bool
    @overload
    def foo(self, bar=..., inplace: bool=...) -> Optional[Animal]: ...

    def foo(
        self, bar=None, inplace = False
    ):
        ...


reveal_type(Animal().foo(bar='a'))
reveal_type(Animal().foo(bar='a', inplace=True))
reveal_type(Animal().foo(bar='a', inplace=False))
reveal_type(Animal().foo(inplace=True))
reveal_type(Animal().foo(inplace=False))
reveal_type(Animal().foo())

inplace: bool
reveal_type(Animal().foo(bar='a', inplace=inplace))
reveal_type(Animal().foo(inplace=inplace))
```

Lots of overloads, but perhaps that's inevitable here

Answer (score 1):

The following issue on Mypy is extremely related: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5486

```py
# main.py

from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Literal, Optional, overload


class Animal:
    @overload
    def foo(self, bar=..., inplace: Literal[False] = ...) -> Animal:
        ...

    @overload
    def foo(self, bar=..., *, inplace: Literal[True]) -> None:
        ...

    def foo(self, bar=None, inplace: bool = False) -> Optional[Animal]:
        ...


reveal_type(Animal().foo(bar="a"))
reveal_type(Animal().foo(inplace=True))
reveal_type(Animal().foo(inplace=False))
```

```
$ mypy main.py 
main.py:21: note: Revealed type is "main.Animal"
main.py:22: note: Revealed type is "None"
main.py:23: note: Revealed type is "main.Animal"
```

By adding a `*,` before the `inplace` argument on the second overload, and removing its default value, it does work as expected. This was suggested on [this comment](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5486#issuecomment-413229343).

This does, however, introduce an issue if you attempt to call the function using positional arguments:

```py
reveal_type(Animal().foo("a", True))
```

```
main.py:25: error: No overload variant of "foo" of "Animal" matches argument types "str", "bool"
main.py:25: note: Possible overload variants:
main.py:25: note:     def foo(self, bar: Any = ..., inplace: Literal[False] = ...) -> Animal
main.py:25: note:     def foo(self, bar: Any = ..., *, inplace: Literal[True]) -> None
main.py:25: note: Revealed type is "Any"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

This issue is mentioned on another comment, and it's suggested that adding another overload could fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a function:

```
def fct(a: str = "", b: str = "", c: str = "", flag_len: bool = False, d: str = "", e: str = ""):
    """Return list of parameters a, b, c, d, e which are not empty strings"""
    lst_non_empty = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, [a, b, c, d , e]))
    if flag_len:
        return len(lst_non_empty)
    return lst_non_empty
```

returning

```
fct(..., flag_len=True, ...) -> int
fct(..., flag_len=False, ...) -> List[str]
```

The following complete code example uses `typing.overload` to encode this into mypy. Just run `$ mypy demo.py` to test if your overload definitions are fine. This is implemented via `assert_type`.

`demo.py`:

```
from typing import List, Literal, Union, overload
from typing_extensions import assert_type

@overload
def fct(a: str = ..., b: str = ..., c: str = ..., flag_len: Literal[False] = ..., d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> List[str]:
    ...

@overload
def fct(*, a: str = ..., b: str = ..., c: str = ..., flag_len: Literal[True], d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> int:
    ...
@overload
def fct(a: str, *, b: str = ..., c: str = ..., flag_len: Literal[True], d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> int:
    ...
@overload
def fct(a: str, b: str, *, c: str = ..., flag_len: Literal[True], d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> int:
    ...
@overload
def fct(a: str, b: str, c: str, flag_len: Literal[True], d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> int:
    ...

@overload
def fct(*, a: str = ..., b: str = ..., c: str = ..., flag_len: bool, d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> Union[int, List[str]]:
    ...
@overload
def fct(a: str, *, b: str = ..., c: str = ..., flag_len: bool, d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> Union[int, List[str]]:
    ...
@overload
def fct(a: str, b: str, *, c: str = ..., flag_len: bool, d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> Union[int, List[str]]:
    ...
@overload
def fct(a: str, b: str, c: str, flag_len: bool, d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> Union[int, List[str]]:
    ...

def fct(a: str = "", b: str = "", c: str = "", flag_len: bool = False, d: str = "", e: str = "") -> Union[int, List[str]]:
    """
    Return list of parameters a, b, c, d, e which are not empty strings.
    flag_len returns just the length of the created list. This argument is in the middle, for demonstrating purposes.
    I would recommend it to be the first default argument, as this reduces the effort for overload.
    """
    lst_non_empty = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, [a, b, c, d , e]))
    if flag_len:
        return len(lst_non_empty)
    return lst_non_empty

def test_fct():
    assert fct("a", "b", "c") == ["a", "b", "c"]
    assert fct("a", "b", "c", True) == 3
    assert fct("a", "b", "c", e="e", d="d") == ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
    assert fct("a", "b", "c", True, e="e", d="d") == 5

# CHECK RETURN TYPE OF FCT VIA MYPY
# $ mypy filename.py

assert_type(fct(), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a"), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b"), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c"), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", d="d"), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", e="d"), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", e="d", d="d"), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", e="d", d="d"), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", e="d", d="d"), List[str])

assert_type(fct(flag_len=False), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", flag_len=False), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", flag_len=False), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", False), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", flag_len=False), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", False, d="d"), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", flag_len=False, d="d"), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", e="d", flag_len=False), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", e="d", d="d", flag_len=False), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", flag_len=False, e="d", d="d"), List[str])
assert_type(fct("a", e="d", flag_len=False, d="d"), List[str])

assert_type(fct(flag_len=True), int)
assert_type(fct("a", flag_len=True), int)
assert_type(fct("a", "b", flag_len=True), int)
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", True), int)
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", flag_len=True), int)
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", True, d="d"), int)
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", flag_len=True, d="d"), int)
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", e="d", flag_len=True), int)
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", e="d", d="d", flag_len=True), int)
assert_type(fct("a", "b", flag_len=True, e="d", d="d"), int)
assert_type(fct("a", e="d", flag_len=True, d="d"), int)

flag: bool = False
assert_type(fct(flag_len=flag), Union[int, List[str]])
assert_type(fct("a", flag_len=flag), Union[int, List[str]])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", flag_len=flag), Union[int, List[str]])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", flag), Union[int, List[str]])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", flag_len=flag), Union[int, List[str]])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", flag, d="d"), Union[int, List[str]])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", flag_len=flag, d="d"), Union[int, List[str]])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", e="d", flag_len=flag), Union[int, List[str]])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", "c", e="d", d="d", flag_len=flag), Union[int, List[str]])
assert_type(fct("a", "b", flag_len=flag, e="d", d="d"), Union[int, List[str]])
assert_type(fct("a", e="d", flag_len=flag, d="d"), Union[int, List[str]])
```

## explanation

The `...` in overload tells mypy that this argument is optional, i.e. it might be present or not.

The `*` in overload tells mypy that everything behind are called as keyword arguments. The increasing star position overloads are needed for positional argument support (if you comment one of the overloads out, some `assert_type` with positional arguments included will fail).

### Why you can't you just write:

```
@overload
def fct(a: str = ..., b: str = ..., c: str = ..., flag_len: Literal[False] = ..., d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> List[str]:
    ...

@overload
def fct(a: str = ..., b: str = ..., c: str = ..., flag_len: Literal[True] = ..., d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> int:
```

`overload` needs to be unique, i.e. `overload`s can't overwrite each other. Otherwise you get `error: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types  [overload-overlap]`. This refers to the case where no parameters are passed at all `fct()` - this would be covered by both overloads.

### Why you can't you just write:

```
@overload
def fct(a: str = ..., b: str = ..., c: str = ..., flag_len: Literal[False] = ..., d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> List[str]:
    ...

@overload
def fct(a: str = ..., b: str = ..., c: str = ..., flag_len: Literal[True], d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> int:
    ...
```

Plain python syntax. You can not have a mandatory argument in between optional ones (if not keyword only arguments). You will get `error: non-default argument follows default argument  [syntax]` **This limitation is the reason, why we need such an lengthy workaround.**

### and there we come up with the next logical step:

```
@overload
def fct(a: str = ..., b: str = ..., c: str = ..., flag_len: Literal[False] = ..., d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> List[str]:
    ...

@overload
def fct(*, a: str = ..., b: str = ..., c: str = ..., flag_len: Literal[True], d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> int:
    ...
```

This works for

```
assert_type(fct(flag_len=True), int)
assert_type(fct(a="a", flag_len=True), int)
assert_type(fct(a="a", c="c", flag_len=True), int)
```

but fails for calls with positional arguments, like

```
assert_type(fct("a", flag_len=True), int)
```

And there we are, iteratively moving the asterisk "*" argument wise backwards until we reach the `flag_len` argument and can finally add

```
@overload
def fct(a: str, b: str, c: str, flag_len: Literal[True], d: str = ..., e: str = ...) -> int:
    ...
```

which covers all further arguments with the optional marker "...", but does not trigger `error: non-default argument follows default argument  [syntax]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@overload
def foo(self, inplace: Literal[False]=..., bar=...) -> Animal:
    ...

@overload
def foo(self, inplace: Literal[True], bar=...,) -> None:
    ...

def foo(self, inplace=False, bar=None):
    ...
```

I changed order of args else second overload should not be correct.

Comment: I can't change the order of the arguments in `def foo` I'm afraid, that would be a breaking change